# Como atualizar dados em tempo real?

Tags: aplicação-web

Sites como Facebook, Twitter até mesmo este que estamos agora estão atualizando seus dados em tempo real, no caso do Facebook: quando um usuário curte algum post automaticamente os dados na sua tela são atualizados e assim por diante, mas fui no network do Chrome e percebi que não existem "requests", como são feita essas atualizações?

Comment: Se não me engano é por Websockets

Comment: Sim, Websockets, a implementação não é tão difícil, entretanto requer algumas horas para entender onde e como aplica-lo de forma que a otimização seja bem feita.

Answer (score 11):

O nome deste tipo de tecnologia é Push (do inglês *Empurre*), onde o servidor inicia uma transação com o cliente (no seu caso, o browser).

É o inverso do que normalmente utilizamos em aplicações web, onde a ação parte do lado do cliente (Pull, do inglês *Puxe*).

Neste mecanismo, o estado do cliente é alterado a pedido do servidor. Existem várias maneiras de implementar este comportamento em browsers modernos:

- **Polling tradicional**: Sua aplicação pergunta de tempos em tempos, via XMLHttpRequest ou equivalente, se o servidor tem alguma atualização de estado.
- **Long-polling**: Sua aplicação mantém uma requisição paralela aberta que só é fechada quando o servidor envia algum conteúdo.
- **Forever Frame**: O mesmo que Long-polling, mas sem o overhead da criação/destruição dos objetos de controle do cliente, e usualmente com uma conexão permanente.
- **WebSockets**: um protocolo relativamente novo (2011) que opera em paralelo ao HTTP e que otimiza a comunicação bidirecional entre cliente e servidor.

Para mais informações, [cheque a entrada na Wikipedia](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tecnologia_Push).