# Gerenciamento de connection pooling pelo PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Costumamos ver nas aplicações *multithreaded* que utilizam conexão com um banco de dados, o uso de um *connection polling*, no qual guarda um "pool" de conexões abertas, dessa forma aumentando a performance fazendo com que não precise ficar abrindo conexões a todo momento ou então ter que aguardar outra *thread* finalizar uma operação no banco.

Eu estava vendo algumas implementações de conexão com o banco utilizando o PDO do PHP e todas não se preocupam com connection pooling, sendo que um webservidor PHP é acessado de forma simultânea por centenas, milhares de conexões (*multithreaded*).

O que mais vejo é algo parecido com o código abaixo, é chamado o método `getConnection()` e no método é criado uma nova instancia para a classe PDO, ou seja, a cada requisição HTTP é criado uma nova conexão sem necessidade, sendo que poderia ser aplicado o uso do *connection pooling*.

```
public function getConnection() {
    try {
        // realiza a conexão
        $this->con = new PDO($this->dbType.":host=".$this->host.";dbname=".$this->db, $this->user, $this->senha, 
        array( PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => $this->persistent ) );
        // realizado com sucesso, retorna conectado

        return $this->con;
    } catch ( PDOException $ex ){ //caso ocorra um erro, retorna o erro
        echo "Erro: ".$ex->getMessage(); 
    }     
}
```

Dúvidas:

O PDO gerencia esse *pool* de conexões automaticamente?

A cada requisição HTTP é criado uma conexão com o banco, feito a operação e fechado em seguida mesmo?

Não existe a possibilidade de aumentar a performance no PDO-PHP usando um *pool* de conexões? Se existir algo do gênero, poderiam me deixar links para estudo, não consigo encontrar material complexo, que aborde bem essa situação.

Comment: Posso responder a segunda pergunta e comentar a terceira. 2) Sim, uma nova conexão é aberta no início da Requisição e fechada no término dela. 3) Muito se fala sobre *Long Pooling* como solução para esse problema pelo menos a nível individual, por usuário. Eu nunca via nenhuma demonstração real que não fosse um chat para técnica. [Nessa resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/26863/250) o membro @OnoSendai citou outras duas formas (uma delas eu nunca havia ouvido falar).

Comment: @BrunoAugusto "Connection pooling" e "long polling" são duas coisas totalmente diferentes, para propósitos diferentes. Connection pooling é uma técnica para gerenciar conexões entre um servidor web e um servidor de banco de dados. Long polling é uma técnica para manter aberta uma conexão HTTP entre um servidor web e um client.

Answer (score 7):

Você não precisa gerenciar isto no PHP, pois se usa `PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT` como `true` o PDO/PHP irá reaproveitar as conexões.

Se você usa o Apache, e configurou-o para trabalhar com 80 `threads`, por exemplo,
verá que em seu banco de dados existirão 80 conexões e se você acompanhar a vida destas conexões, verá que elas durarão o mesmo tempo que cada thread do webserver.

A otimização que você procura está muito ligada à configuração do webserver. Aqui entra a experiência e os testes de carga.

Comment: Nunca usei conexões persistentes com a PDO então, ainda assim, é persistente por usuário, certo?

Comment: @BrunoAugusto, é persistente de acordo com Drive, db host e db user