# Padrão Singleton para comunicação com banco de dados

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, design-pattern, singleton

Em PHP quando faço um Singleton é criado uma instância para cada requisição que tenta abrir uma conexão com o banco de dados **ou** instanciando uma única vez ela "sempre" vai ficar em memória para todas as requisições?

exemplo:

```
class Connect{

    private static $conn;//qual o escopo dessa variavel?

    /**
    *   Padrão singleton
    */
    public static function getConnection(){
        if(self::$conn==NULL){
            //vai entrar aqui toda vez que uma requisição do usuario tenta uma comunicação com o bd?
            self::$conn= new PDO(...);
        }       
        return self::$conn;
    }
```

Comment: Não compreendo muito de php, mas algo me diz que o código está errado, como a variável privada e estática. Acho que a variável deveria ser somente privada e o método sim deve ser estático. Por favor, me corrijam se eu estiver errado.

Comment: Não está errado. O singleton é exatamente dessa forma, em PHP. Você precisa de uma variável estática (porque ela é estática, rsrs), e assim a instância continuará ativa lá dentro. Então, caso seja nulo (o que só vai acontecer uma vez), ele instancia `PDO`. Se não, ele retorna a conexão já instanciada. Não há nada de errado (com o código, não falo da utilização do  pattern)

Comment: @Rubico Não há como acessar um membro de instância pelo método estático. De qual instância estaria falando? Na verdade há casos no padrão que se faz o oposto e há métodos de instância (não todos) que acessam membros estáticos (normal já que só existe um).

Comment: Esquece gente, falei besteira das brabas. Assim como o @WallaceMaxters falou, ele deve ser estática, de outra forma o seu estado seria preservado pela instância e não pela classe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O padrão Singleton é justamente isso (eventualmente pode ser um pouco mais sofisticado). Por ser estático não há instanciação de fato, e a lógica do método garante que a conexão seja aberta apenas uma vez, afinal, a primeira vez a variável privada `$conn`, que tem escopo privado (só a classe a vê), é nula então é estabelecida uma conexão, após isso, não entra mais no `if` e só retorna o objeto da conexão. Então ficará na memória enquanto o *script* estiver rodando.

Eu costumo dizer que esse tipo de coisa é muita complicação para algo que será bem efêmero, mas tá na moda fazer assim. *Design patterns* costumam ser abusados, o Singleton é o campeão disto, em PHP então...

- [Mais sobre o assunto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/18860/101).
- [Específico para PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/97547/101).
- [Resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9227695/221800).

Comment: Não entendo o negativo. O Singleton está bem explicado. E concordo, realmente o abuso que ocorre nisso, parece as vezes deixar a aplicação engessada.

Comment: O que você quer dizer por abusado? Desculpa mas não consegui compreender.

Comment: @Rubico usa quando não precisa. Dá para fazer algo simples, opta-se pelo complicado.

Comment: Se você precisa uma vez, por que não instanciar só uma vez? Será que é tão difícil assim? as vezes o singleton é só uma complicação desnecessária

Comment: @WallaceMaxters entendo o seu ponto de vista, mas se é algo que deve ser instanciado somente uma vez, porque não evitar a falha humana? Talvez um desenvolvedor novo e desavisado possa começar a criar diversas instâncias e isso ser prejudicial para o seu projeto. Singleton é algo válido nesse caso, não?

Comment: [Por que não devemos usar Singleton?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/18860/por-que-n%C3%A3o-devemos-usar-singleton/18863)

Comment: Tentar corrigir a falta de informação de um programador com código não acho uma solução muito agradável. O Singleton não é de todo inútil, mas as vezes desnecessário. É o que quero dizer.

Comment: Eu não tenho nada contra o Singleton. Acho ele útil. Só acho que ele é abusado. É claro que por vezes outros padrões são mais abusados ainda para evitar o Singleton :) No PHP, um monte de coisa é abusada porque pegou moda fazer coisas complexas onde não precisa. Aí o cara que acha que o complexo é bom negativa respostas que dizem o que ele não gosta. Justamente por isso a pessoa não comenta dizendo onde está o erro da resposta.

Comment: Galera não queria discutir sobre Singleton, nunca vai ter fim, ja li varios assuntos sobre o mesmo, a questão principal é, cada usuario faz uma requisição ao meu servidor. cada requisição acessa n vezes o banco, a minha pergunta é, a variavel estatica sera uma para cada requisição ou uma para todas as requisições?

Comment: Acredito que essa resposta esteja errada. Como o php abre um processo e mata ele ao fim da requisição o singleton não será o mesmo entre duas requisições. Dentro de uma requisição o singleton funciona como esperado, mas entre requisições não.

Comment: Mais especificamente quem mata o processo php é o servidor web. No caso de ser Apache será um processo por requisição no caso de estar utilizando php-fpm ele gerencia os processos pra não não ficar utilizando um por conexão, mas da mesma forma ele mata o processo com frequência.

Comment: @ViniciusZaramella eu não falei isso, pelo contrário, falei o oposto do que está citando. Ele manterá a conexão aberta enquanto o *script* estiver rodando. Por isso usar essas coisas em PHP faz tão pouco sentido.

Comment: Sim, mas em uma requisição no meu caso pode ser abertas varias comunicações com o BD, por isso achei interessante manter uma conexão aberta por requisição para não ficar criando por exemplo 5 conexão em uma unica requisição. Imagina 100 requisições são abertas 500 conexões com o BD. Por isso pensei em fazer Singleton. Obrigado pela resposta, o que eu queria saber era exatamente isso "enquanto o script estiver rodando.", eu fiquei um pouco confuso enquanto ao escopo de uma variavel estatica da classe, se seu valor era visto para qualquer requisição.

Comment: O que pode acontecer tambem, eu estou usando PDO, mas poderia ser uma outra classe de comunicação, eu não me aprofundei sobre como funciona, as vezes ele pode criar até um pool de conexões. ai ja seria uma outra história, ai não faria sentido mesmo fazer singleton. Mas não to afirmando nada, só que desconheço o funcionamento dele, e discutir isso ja caberia em uma outra pergunta ou uma lida na documentação ja responderia.

Comment: a respeito do pool esta ai, bem interessante http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/26873/gerenciamento-de-connection-pooling-pelo-pdo

Comment: Mas porque você abriria várias conexões em uma requisição? Há anos trabalhei em uma das linguagens mais toscas para gerenciar conexões com banco de dados e outras organizações de código, não conhecia Singleton ou solução semelhante, os códigos eram absurdamente maiores e mais complexos que qualquer *script* PHP, e eu nunca tive problemas de abrir 2 vezes a mesma conexão. Escopo é uma coisa, visibilidade e tempo de vida são coisas diferentes. Singleton, Pool, tudo isso pode ser útil mas não é em 99% (ou mais) dos *scripts* PHP. PHP não é Java.

Comment: Por exemplo uma requisição precisa fazer uns 5 `selects` ou mais, para recuperar dados de um objeto, seria interessante de manter a conexão aberta, eu vejo nesse ponto de vista.

Comment: Sim, mas ela fica aberta até que seja fechada. Abra, faça as 5 e feche no final do *script* (ou deixe fechar sozinho, ainda que eu não goste disto). Não tem porque ficar abrindo e fechando. Eu entendo que muita gente anda fazendo isso, mas não sei porque. Não tem motivo pra fazer, é só uma coisa errada que as pessoas ficam copiando. Por isso que eu falo que as pessoas precisam aprender a programar e não seguir "boas práticas". Precisa entender o que está acontecendo com o código e tomar uma decisão do melhor caminho. Programar é procurar a melhor solução e não copiar os erros dos outros.